# Noun links Adjective

Tags: grammar

> It was a hot day, the **sky big** and white over their heads, and the
>   children seemed to be running

Why can a noun directly link an adjective? What is the grammar knowledge point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The sky big and white" is just another version of "The sky **was** big and white".
As Auxiliary verbs can be [omitted](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gmdS3VRl3RM) in informal writing, the sentence is grammatical and makes sense.